# Not getting XY image size after using "zoom to rect" in a matplotlib figure when using GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, mouseevent

I am trying to get a `ROI` (region of interest) from a loaded image. Using the "Zoom to rect" option from the `matplotlib` figure and sing a GUI with 2 buttons:

[image: Zoom to rect]

Button1: "LoadImage"- load and plot the image and should also save into 2 list the new XY size of the zoomed image
Button2: "RunimgeAnalisis" should read the information of the 2 list in order to crop the ROI out of the original image

Problem: my code is not saving in the lists (xlist/ylist) the new XY information after using the "Zoom to rect". Whe running the code WITHOUT the GUI(bottons), I do obtain the XY size after selecting the zoom with the mouse but when implementing the code into a GUI-buttons, the new XY values of the zoom are not passed to the list. Right after selecting the zoom area in the image with the mouse,  the values are never passed to the execution of the program.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

xlist =[] 
ylist =[] 
image_path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Images/TestImage1.raw' 

# Load image, the image is ploted and the user will select with the mouse a ROI with the 
#zoom rectangle option from matplotlib a new (x1, x2) and (y1,y2) will be saved on xlist ylist
def LoadImage(image_path):
    InputImage = np.fromfile(image_path, dtype='uint16', count=3840 \* 2160)
    InputImage = np.reshape(InputImage, (2160, 3840))
    xlist = []
    ylist = []
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.imshow(InputImage, interpolation_stage='rgba')

    #A ROI form the image is selected with the zoom rectantgle from matpotlib (Declare and register  callbacks)
    def on_xlims_change(event_ax):
        xlist.append(event_ax.get_xlim())
        print("updated xlims: ", event_ax.get_xlim())

    def on_ylims_change(event_ax):
        ylist.append(event_ax.get_ylim())
        print("updated ylims: ", event_ax.get_ylim())
    plt.colorbar()
   
#with the information from xlist and ylist, the ROI is croped and saved in ImageRegion for
#further analisis  
def RunImageAnalisis(xlist, ylist):
     x1 = int(xlist[0])
     x2 = int(xlist[1])
     y1 = int(ylist[0])
     y2 = int(ylist[1])
     ImageRegion = ImageToProcess[y1:y2, x1:x2] 

#GUI with 2 buttons: LoadImage and RunAnalisis
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Image Tool")
MainForm = tk.Canvas(root, width=145, height=320)
MainForm.grid(columnspan =3, row=2)

bottom_Name = tk.StringVar()
Run_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Run', command=lambda:RunImageAnalisis(xlist, ylist), height=1, width=9, fg="black", bg="grey")
bottom_Name.set("Run")
Run_btn.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='nw', padx=15, pady=15)

bottom_Name1 = tk.StringVar()
GetData_btn = tk.Button(root, text='LoadIm', command=lambda:LoadImage(image_path),  height=1, width=9, fg="black", bg="grey")
bottom_Name.set("LoadIm")
GetData_btn.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='nw',pady=15)

root.mainloop()
```

**I tried:** I ran the code without using the GUI-implementation and this is working  correctly. The new xy values are correctly saved in the xlist and ylist after selecting the zoom area with the mouse

But when I ran the GUI implemented code on debug mode, I could corroborate that after selecting with the mouse the image zoom area, the values are never passed to the xlist/ylist. Seems like program execution is hanging on the image and data never return to the program and thus variable explorer is empty

**Expected Result :** Button "Load" should load and plot the image. then the user should select with the mouse the zoom area and new xy values should be saved in xlist and ylist

Then, button "RunImageAnalisis" should use new XY values saved on xlist and ylist to crop the ROI out of the original image. This new ROI image array will be used for further analysis

thank you for your help